# DSolve solution of two unknowns

Tags: differential-equations

I have one problem with the solution of the system of two differential equations. I waited hours, but Mathematica didn't give me a solution. Is there any way to obtain the results if we suppose that we know 8 roots of the characteristic equation in the form s1,2,3,4=+/-a1+/-b1*i and s5,6,7,8=+/-a2+/-b2*i? I need a solution where will be 8 unknown constants, of course, which will be obtained for a initial conditions.

```
DSolve[{y1''''[x] + y1''[x] + y1[x] - y2[x] == 0, 
y2''''[x] + y2''[x] + y2[x] - 2 y1[x] == 0}, {y1[x], y2[x]}, x]
```

Comment: I get the answer in 0.11 seconds, V 10.02 ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Hjl.png)

Comment: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HyUk2.png)

Comment: I don't know what is a problem with my code, just working and working. Thanks anyway.

Comment: what version of M are you using? Did you try with clean kernel? what OS?

Comment: yes, didn't work... win7 64, math 9

Comment: Well, then it looks like it was something that was fixed in V 10.2

Comment: maybe, thnx for the answer

Comment: @Nasser  Yes, it does run a long time under Mathematica 9.0.1.